# "GC freed" log in xamarin (it's about memory usage)

Tags: c#, android, memory-leaks, xamarin.forms, out-of-memory

I need some help.

I am using ffimageloading.
I have a list of images...with a several number of images.
In output I can see:

> Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 23899(1507KB) AllocSpace objects, 43(1032KB) LOS objects, 39% free, 20MB/34MB, paused 154us total 9.754ms

then, according I open, close and reopen the lists page, the percentual decreases:

> Explicit concurrent mark sweep GC freed 19286(1148KB) AllocSpace objects, 41(984KB) LOS objects, 35% free, 29MB/45MB, paused 138us total 13.067ms

until 0. When it's zero (about 50 minutes open and closing the lists), the app crashs with out of memory error.

are these logs about RAM memory? What are they about? Should it occures if I am using ffimageloading with cached image? 
I need to understand this....someone more experient here?

Comment: You are continuously loading images in memory until 0% of free memory is left, after which you get the error as expected (exactly as it says). You'll have to make sure the images either don't get reloaded or get properly disposed. How you do that is a much larger topic which you can probably find a lot of information about online.

Comment: mmmm, I thought the plugin were enough...but I think, maybe, its not

Comment: Memory leak, you need find it out.

Comment: I tried. I don't know more what try.
I searched so much about this plugin and I coudn't solve the dawn problem.